# Because VISUAL STUDIO CODE displays the folder and subfolder on the same level

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a subfolder inside a folder in angular. Unfortunately I create them on the same level. I tried doing the same thing in Windows Explorer, but the problem persists. Why are the other folders and subfolders of the project displayed normally? That is, with a hierarchical tree structure?[image]

Answer (score 2):

The backslash between the two folders mean that "components" is inside "comunicazioni2". If they were at same level, one would appear at the top of the other.

Answer (score 0):

They are not on the same level they are just shown this way because there is only 1 subfolder. If you add another sub folder it will show it the normal way with indentation.